# What is Product Variable and Schema in cs cart

Tags: php, cs-cart

I am working on the documents section in order to add some extra information needed when printing orders and I am having some issues adding a variable I need showing. I am using CS-Cart version 4.4.3, going to Admin Panel > Design > Documents > Invoice > Products Table > Item Description.

As shown on the screenshot attached, we have some standard variables provided by cs-cart, which includes p.procude_code (SKU), but I also have a different product code which is a product feature, and I have no idea how to get it showing here.

The product code I want to fetch, is shown on the product_feature table as the number 8, which I want to grab his value and show it there.

```
    "8": {
      "feature_id": "8",
      "company_id": "1",
      "feature_type": "T",
      "parent_id": "7",
      "display_on_product": "Y",
      "display_on_catalog": "Y",
      "display_on_header": "N",
      "description": "Product Code",
      "lang_code": "en",
      "prefix": "",
      "suffix": "",
      "categories_path": "",
      "full_description": "",
      "status": "A",
      "comparison": "N",
      "position": "0",
      "group_position": "0",
      "value": "Z000116",
      "variant_id": "0",
      "value_int": null
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is used for avoid direct static content in code.We will update update content in admin panel and will use that variable in code like __(points).End user can modify  text anytime by admin panel